# GPS.ane for my app and i keep getting an error Line 55, Column 50 1120: Access of undefined property onClickStop

Tags: actionscript, adobe

**trying to use the GPS.ane for my app and I keep getting an error

> "Line 55, Column 50   1120: Access of undefined property onClickStop."

this is the line that is giving me the headache I think I am missing something small but i cant find it. The app is as you will think gives out the latitude and longitude of where you are at. thank you for you help  **

**package  {

```
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.gps.Gps;
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.gps.LocationAccuracy;
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.gps.Location;
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.gps.GpsEvent;
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.nativePermissions.PermissionCheck;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.dependency.OverrideAir;


import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;
import flash.events.InvokeEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;

import flash.filesystem.File;

import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    private var _exPermissions:PermissionCheck = new PermissionCheck();

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate);
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleDeactivate);
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys);


        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        startBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onClickStart);
        stopBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onClickStop);

        checkPermissions();
    }

        private function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.removeEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
    }

    private function handleActivate(e:Event):void 
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
    }

    private function handleDeactivate(e:Event):void 
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
    }

    private function handleKeys(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
        }
    }

    private function checkPermissions():void
    {
        // first you need to make sure you have access to the Location API
        var permissionState:int;

        if(_exPermissions.os == PermissionCheck.ANDROID)
        {
            permissionState = _exPermissions.check(PermissionCheck.SOURCE_LOCATION);
        }
        else if(_exPermissions.os == PermissionCheck.IOS)
        {
            permissionState = _exPermissions.check(PermissionCheck.SOURCE_LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE);
        }

        if (permissionState == PermissionCheck.PERMISSION_UNKNOWN || permissionState == PermissionCheck.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        {
            if(_exPermissions.os == PermissionCheck.ANDROID)
            {
                _exPermissions.request(PermissionCheck.SOURCE_LOCATION, onRequestResult);
            }
            else if(_exPermissions.os == PermissionCheck.IOS)
            {
                _exPermissions.request(PermissionCheck.SOURCE_LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE, onRequestResult);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textDisplay.appendText("permissions are already ok, you can use gps features."+ "\n");
            init();
        }

        function onRequestResult($state:int):void
        {
            if ($state != PermissionCheck.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                textDisplay.appendText("You did not allow the app the required permissions!"+ "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                textDisplay.appendText("necessary permissions are now granted."+ "\n");
                init();
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClickStart (evt:TouchEvent):void{
        textDisplay.appendText("Location Uptade Started.\n");
        // use the start method to get gps information periodically (the gps icon will be shown at your device status bar)
 Gps.location.addEventListener(GpsEvent.LOCATION_UPDATE, onLocationUpdate);
 Gps.location.start(LocationAccuracy.HIGH, 0, 5000);
        startBtn.alpha = 0.5;
        stopBtn.alpha = 1;
    }
    public function onClickstop (evt:TouchEvent):void{
        textDisplay.appendText("Location Uptade Stopped.\n");
        // simply stop the gps service when you don't need to get location information periodically anymore.
 Gps.location.removeEventListener(GpsEvent.LOCATION_UPDATE, onLocationUpdate);
 Gps.location.stop();
        startBtn.alpha = 1;
        stopBtn.alpha = 0.5;
    }

         function onLocationUpdate(e:GpsEvent):void
 {

     textDisplay.appendText(" ------------------------------- onLocationUpdate"+ "\n");
     var loc:Location = e.param;
     textDisplay.appendText("accuracy = " + loc.accuracy+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("altitude = " + loc.altitude+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("bearing = " + loc.bearing+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("latitude = " + loc.latitude+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("longitude = " + loc.longitude+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("provider = " + loc.provider+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("speed = " + loc.speed+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("time = " + loc.time+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("---------------------------------"+ "\n");
 }

    private function myDebuggerDelegate($ane:String, $class:String, $msg:String):void
    {
        textDisplay.appendText($ane+"("+$class+") "+$msg+ "\n");
    }

            private function init():void
    {
        // remove this line in production build or pass null as the delegate
        OverrideAir.enableDebugger(myDebuggerDelegate);

        Gps.init(); // call init only once in your project

          // will return null if no known last location has been found
 Gps.location.getLastLocation(onLocationResult);

 // may take a while depending on when gps info is found
 Gps.location.getCurrentLocation(onLocationResult);

         function onLocationResult($result:Location):void
 {
     if (!$result)
     {
         textDisplay.appendText("location is null"+ "\n");
         return;
     }

     textDisplay.appendText("accuracy = " + $result.accuracy+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("altitude = " + $result.altitude+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("bearing = " + $result.bearing+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("latitude = " + $result.latitude+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("longitude = " + $result.longitude+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("provider = " + $result.provider+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("speed = " + $result.speed+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("time = " + $result.time+ "\n");
     textDisplay.appendText("---------------------------------"+ "\n");
 }
    }

}
```

}
**

Answer (score 0):

stopBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onClickStop);

public function onClickstop (evt:TouchEvent):void{

Your function has a low case s in stop, but when you refer to it you use a capital S.

Think that's all that's wrong